# valueremapper does not read the csv file

Tags: magmi

Currently I'm strugling with the valueremapper option within the value replacer plugin of MAGMI. Somehow he get's the item id from my current column(Category_copy), but it does not map it to the correct value in the corresponding csv located on my website. (remapcategories.csv). It seems that he is not using the csv.

My case:
I create a new field category_ids. And as a value I put in:

> {{
>   ValueRemapper::use_csv('http://mydomain.com/remapcategories.csv')->map({item.Category_copy})
>   }}

My csv file looks like this. There is no markup, no quotes and no heading (just like the magmi manual suggests)

```
HARDWARE|LAPTOPS;3
SOFTWARE|GAMES;5
```

I'm getting the following error message while uploading:

> Invalid category ids found for sku 718037780566:HARDWARE|LAPTOPS

It seems that it does get the value from the Category_copy, but it won't map it to "3".

Any experienced magmi user who can help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use "/" instead of |

Also do not use absolute path for your CSV

hope this helps